# preg_replace error dont know why

Tags: html, dom, replace

Have this code... its suppose to strip a very specific JS line out of a form to generate a non-valid html so I can work with later with a dom parser but its giving this error

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 29 in E:\xampp-portable\htdocs\ingeniat\system\replace_html.php on line 18
```

Here is the code I have no idea why this is happening hope you guys can help!

```
<?php
//<input class="correct" readonly="readonly" onmouseover="return overlib('<div 
//class="correctness">Respuesta correcta: -2</div>', STICKY, MOUSEOFF, CAPTION, '
//Respuesta correcta', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFFF');" onmouseout="return nd();" 
//name="resp636911_2" value="-2" size="2" type="text">


$cont = file_get_contents('../test_files/answer.php');
$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = '/onmouseover="return overlib('."'/";
$patterns[1] = "/', STICKY, MOUSEOFF, CAPTION, 'Respuesta correcta', FGCOLOR, '#FFFFFF');".'" onmouseout="return nd();"/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '>';
$replacements[1] = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $cont);

?>
```

The fragment of teh HTML I am targeting its in the comments at the beginning of the code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to escape all special chars on regex pattern. Detail you can check here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html.

Try this code:

```
$cont = '<input class="correct" readonly="readonly" onmouseover="return overlib(\'<div 
class="correctness">Respuesta correcta: -2</div>\', STICKY, MOUSEOFF, CAPTION, \'Respuesta correcta\', FGCOLOR, \'#FFFFFF\');" onmouseout="return nd();" 
name="resp636911_2" value="-2" size="2" type="text">';

$patterns = array();
$patterns[0] = "/onmouseover=\"return overlib\(\'/s";
$patterns[1] = "/\'\, STICKY\, MOUSEOFF\, CAPTION\, \'Respuesta correcta\', FGCOLOR\, \'#FFFFFF\'\);\"\sonmouseout=\"return nd\(\);\"/";

$replacements = array();
$replacements[0] = '>';
$replacements[1] = '';

$var = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $cont);
var_dump($var);
```